# Is Page.Load the earliest point in the page life cycle to add Response.AppendHeader?

Tags: asp.net

Is Page.Load the earliest point in the Page.Load life cycle to add Response.AppendHeader?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call `Response.AppendHeader()` at any time before headers are sent.  There are several events before `Load` that you could call it in.  `Init` would be the obvious one.

What are you trying to do exactly?

EDIT: From your comment, you should be able to add the headers anywhere, but you should read the documentation for [AppendHeader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpresponse.appendheader.aspx), specifically:

> If you use the AppendHeader method to
>   send cache-specific headers and at the
>   same time use the cache object model
>   (Cache) to set cache policy, HTTP
>   response headers that pertain to
>   caching (Cache-Control, Expires,
>   Last-Modified, Pragma, and Vary) might
>   be deleted when the cache object model
>   is used. This behavior enables ASP.NET
>   to maintain the most restrictive
>   settings. For example, consider a page
>   that includes user controls. If those
>   controls have conflicting cache
>   policies, the most restrictive cache
>   policy will be used. If one user
>   control sets the header
>   "Cache-Control: Public" and another
>   user control sets the more restrictive
>   header "Cache-Control: Private" via
>   calls to SetCacheability, then the
>   "Cache-Control: Private" header will
>   be sent with the response.

So be wary with your cache control headers ;)

Comment: I'm adding a few headers including ones related to caching and one for the X-Robots-Tag.

Answer (score 2):

ASP.NET pages run the following events in this order:

```
PreInit
Init
InitComplete
PreLoad
Load
LoadComplete
PreRender
SaveStateComplete
Render
Unload
```

The `Response` is wired up before `PreInit` is triggered, so you can call `Response.AddHeader` as soon as you want.